# Linux: Using grep command to find how many lines do not start with a vowel

Tags: linux, bash, grep, command

So I came up with two command:

1: `grep -c [^[^aeiouAEIOU]] filename.txt;` result:52331

2: `grep -v -c [^aeiouAEIOU] filename.txt;` result:52333

These two commands are same to me but with different result.

Please help, this make no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Those two commands indeed do different things, and none of them actually does what you think:

```
grep -c [^[^aeiouAEIOU]] filename.txt
```

You can't really nest `[^...]` expressions. Instead, this regular expression is interpreted as `[^[^aeiouAEIOU]` concatenated with `]`.  That is, it will match anywhere in the line any combination of a character that isn't `[`, `^`, or a vowel, and `]`. For example, these strings will match: `b]`, `c]`, `#]`, `;]`; and these will not: `a]`, `E]`, `c`, `d`. And "anywhere in the line" means that the `grep` command above will count lines such as `aaab]`, `i uc]`, etc.

As for your second command,

```
grep -v -c [^aeiouAEIOU] filename.txt
```

Here you have double negation. First, `[^aeiouAEIOU]` matches any character other than a vowel. On the other hand, the `-v` option passed to `grep` inverts the match, so it will match any lines not matched by `[^aeiouAEIOU]`. The end effect is, basically, that you're telling `grep`: "Count all lines that don't have symbols other than `aeiouAEIOU`". That is, it will count only lines that contain only vowels.

Two commands that actually *should* give you the number of lines that don't start with a vowel are:

```
grep -c ^[^aeiouAEIOU] filename.txt
grep -v -c ^[aeiouAEIOU] filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this:

```
grep -Ewcv "*[aeiou]*" filename.txt
```